# Security of locally stored password

Tags: security

Assuming that many people use one password for everything he/she has.
So when an account is created in a website, what prevents a maintainer of the website, who apparently has access to the account database, from attempt using the same account name and password to log in other websites? Do they always one-way hash the password?

Comment: This is like asking "if I hand someone $2 for a taco at Taco Bell, what prevents them from pocketing it?" Well, nothing really. A malicious party will do malicious things.

Answer (score 2):

> What prevents a maintainer of the website, who apparently has access to the account database, from attempt using the same account
>   name and password to log in other websites?

Minor issues like moral scruples aside, nothing.  As an end user (unless you are dealing with an enterprise service provider whose security processes are regularly audited), you have no guarantees about how a service handles your password.  Maybe they use a high iteration uniquely salted PBKDF to store your password.  Maybe they dump it all in a text file.

When you sign up for a service you are effectively giving someone you have never met and may have no reason to trust a password.  If you also happen to use that password to secure, for instance, your online banking, then you have only yourself to blame if something bad happens.

Comment: There is evidence that service providers do NOT hash their passwords: [Epic blunder by Adobe](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/11/how-an-epic-blunder-by-adobe-could-strengthen-hand-of-password-crackers/).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, really. One way to reduce the risk is to use different random passwords on each site, with a local tool to remember them for you.

Even if the password were stored in a hashed and salted manner, they are in the clear when the server receives them. They could reuse them "in real time" and say with a straight face that they don't have clear text passwords.

[OpenID](http://openid.net/) and such aleviate the problem in a way, by putting the trust at a single place, like Google. You can also run your own OpenID provider. It is not that hard, but few bother.

One OpenID enabled site is Stack Overflow. I log in with my Google account, so even a malicious StackOverflow admin can't steal my account for other purposes. Google could do what it wants with my password, although I beleive the cost of a breach of passwords is for them more expensive than what they could make by using it to impersonate me.

Finally, to be on the safe side, the password I use for Google is not used anywhere else.